# How to send 2 requests consistently

Tags: ios, iphone, web

I want to send first request with user coordinates on server and then I got response I want to send second request and get response with user neighborhoods, but my second request is sending then my first not finished, I use singleton for web server class and my method, that send first and second request looks like this, how can I fix it?

```
   [[WebRequests sharedInstance] makeRequest:@"coordinates" login:nil password:nil token:webToken name:nil age:nil status:nil lat:lat lon:lon time:dateString];

  [[WebRequests sharedInstance] makeRequest:@"neighborhoods" login:nil password:nil token:webToken name:nil age:nil status:nil lat:nil lon:nil time:nil];
```

I use AFNetworking 2.0. I think I can to send second request after first response in its body, but I think there is a best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use completion blocks provided by `AFNetworking`. Just place your second request inside success block of your first request and then the second one will be called once the first is successfully finished